How to create request with plaintext body
Has controller FakeController which has to accepts JSONs and plaintext by request:
public function check(Request $request, int $twin): mixed {
    echo "twin = " . $twin . PHP_EOL;
    echo "request = " . print_r($request, true) . PHP_EOL;
    return null;
}

Call this method with JSON:
app(FakeController::class)->check(new Request($json), 123);

Success - all echoes inside check reached and print expected data.
Then try to call method check with plaintext:
$message = 'some text';
app(FakeController::class)->check(new Request($message), 123);

check silently unreachable.
Guess that's why new Request($message) produced almost empty request with no 'some text' inside.
So, how to create request with plaintext body?
I know how to do it with Http client, but Http client used mostly for external calls.

Does this answer your question? Create a Laravel Request object on the fly

When you say new Request($json) works, is $json here also a string?

@jef I saw this thread before. Even check it - it's completely about JSON, and not useful for plaintext body

@apokryfos. No, little bit complex:
$maybeJSON = json_decode($message, true);
if (is_array($maybeJSON)) {
$result = app(FakeController::class)->check(new Request($maybeJSON), $maybeTwin); }

As far as I can tell there's no constructor for Request that accepts a string as the first argument, however that should raise an error if you do pass a string. Laravel does not recommend using this way of testing controllers as well and Request basically needs an array of input parameters.

That's work:
//$message = scalar or JSON-string
$maybeTwin = 123
$maybeJSON = json_decode($message, true);
if (is_array($maybeJSON)) { // JSON here
    $request = new Request($maybeJSON);
    $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $result = app(FakeController::class)->check($request, $maybeTwin);
} else { // scalar value here
    $request = new Request(content: $message);
    $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    $result = app(FakeController::class)->check($request, $maybeTwin);
}

